# Avoid the collapsing effect on TreeView after updating data

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, treeview, prism

I have a TreeView used to display events. It works great, however every time new events are coming in and populating the tree collapse the tree again to the original position. That is very annoying when the refresh time is less than 1 second and it does not allow the user to interact with the items of the tree.
Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

```
<TreeView Margin="1" BorderThickness="0" Name="eventsTree" ItemsSource="{Binding EventAlertContainers}" 
              Background="#00000000" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="14" 
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C:EventAlertContainer}" ItemsSource="{Binding EventAlerts}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="3,0" Source="Resources\Process_info_32.png" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C:EventAlert}" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0" Source="Resources\clock2_32.jpg" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C:Event}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0" Source="Resources\Task_32.png" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you refresh the entire `EventAlertContainers` collection, this will happen. WPF doesn't know that the items in the new collection are the same as the items in the old colleciton.

Instead of repopulating, keep the same collections, and take care to only add and remove items where they have changed. Make sure your collections are `ObservableCollection`s or support `INotifyCollecitonChanged` and only make the bare minimum changes (adding, removing and updating) as necessary.

Comment: I cannot change that. I would need to engineer something different.

Comment: So are you binding directly to your models? If you are, you will tend to have problems like these. You should wrap them in view-models that provide the functionality that the view needs, i.e. the collection changed notifications.

Comment: The viewModel contains EventAlertContainers which is updated every minute and shows the whole data set of alerts (new and old).Is there any way to do that?

Comment: As I say, don't repopulate the whole data set. If you don't have any control over this, then create another mirrored data set for binding to your tree view. Write some code to detect changes on your source data set, and copy *only* the changes into your mirrored data set.